# Smart Edge Revalidation , Last-Modified, and Dynamic pages

Tags: cloudflare

Assuming I implement If-Modified headers on my website, would Cloudflare’s Smart Edge Revalidation activate and cache pages which currently have cf-cache-status DYNAMIC or do I have to explicitly enable caching (via cache rules) for those dynamic pages first?

I tried an experiment. I enabled Cloudflare caching (via cache rules) on a dynamic page which has If-Modified headers, and then I updated the date on the If-Modified to a newer date and reloaded the page several times. Although it was served from the Cloudflare cache, it never served with the updated If-Modified date/updated version of the page, so it seems that the Cloudflare server couldn’t bother to check my server for the most up-to-date If-Modified header results upon my reloads - hence, it never updated the CF cache with the newer If-Modified date & page. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Here is my test page, actually (feel free to load it and check its headers): https://www.go-parts.com/ps-product-new.php?make=Honda&model=Civic&sku=1D3211C

Currently it is returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK =>
Date => Mon, 19 Feb 2024 19:02:12 GMT
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection => close
x-frame-options => SAMEORIGIN
last-modified => Sun, 01 Jan 2023 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control => max-age=14400
expires => Mon, 19 Feb 2024 21:52:43 GMT
vary => Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
strict-transport-security => max-age=31536000
CF-Cache-Status => HIT
```

But if this page is loaded outside of the current CF cache, it will return its TRUE last-modifed date of '2024-02-19 10:50:00'. So what settings am I supposed to use to make the CF server check the page's last-modified date ON EACH AND EVERY LOAD (and then update its CF cache for this page if the last-modified date is updated and calls for it)?